# How to get Rhythmbox stations back!

Tags: rhythmbox, music, internet-radio

I accidentally removed the internet radio station *HBR1 Tronic Lounge* in the category *House* from Rhythmbox. Does anyone know how to get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the appropriate link at http://www.hbr1.com/ (it will say "OGG Vorbis", and is under the header "Tronic Lounge") to download an .m3u to add back to Rhythmbox.

To import the file into Rhythmbox, go to "Import File" then select your .m3u file. From there, you can change the name and category of the station.

Comment: Once you have downloaded it, what do you do with it? :-)

Comment: You goto "Import File" then select your .m3u file. from there you can change the name and category of the station.